# Change AccessKey=S on SmallSearchInputBox

Tags: accessibility

We are having an issue with SharePoint 2010 and the OOTB SmallSearchInputBox control.  It renders the `accessKey="S"` for the search control.  Is there anyway to override this as the Search Access key needs to be set to '4' and our Skip Navigation 'S'?

I know that we can override the delegate control but just wondering if there is a simpler way of changing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to alter the accesskey after the page has loaded. You can do it with jQuery or plain javascript. Or you can do it with the new mQuery (Microsft javascript library like jQuery):

```
m$.ready(function() {
    m$("#SearchBox > div > input").attr("accesskey", "4");
});
```

m$ or mQuery is only available in SharePoint 2013 or greater.

If you want more about mQuery, read a blog post on [spdevlab.com](http://spdevlab.com/2013/07/01/getting-started-with-mquerym-in-sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: m$.ready(function(){ m$("#SearchBox > div > input").attr("accesskey", "4"); });